# How to enable unsafe query note back in DataGrip? If I click execute and suppress once

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

as you know ,when execute command like `delete from t;`  in DataGrip .
we will see a yellow note at the bottom of console .
If I click `execute and suppress` once ,how to enable it back.

Answer (score 6):

I've found it.

follow this:

Preferences/Settings | Database | Query Execution | Show warning before running potentially unsafe queries.